# Oracle SQL Trying to get Percentage of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am using Oracle SQL Developer and am trying to get percentages on my table.

My Current Query is:

```
select 
  decode(grouping(life), 1, 'Total', life) as "LifeName", 
  sum(case 
        when task is not null and to_char(datee, 'MM') = '08' 
          and to_char(datee, 'YYYY') = '2013' 
        then 1 
        else 0 
      end) as "MonthStatus"
from life_lk, task_c
where life_lk.life_id = task_c.life_id
group by rollup(life)
```

The current output I get is:

```
LifeName             MonthStatus
dog                     5
bear                    20
cat                     1
Fish                    4
Total                   30
```

However, I want the output to be:

```
LifeName             MonthStatus           Percent
dog                     5                     16
bear                   20                     66
cat                     1                      3
Fish                    4                     13
Total                  30                    100
```

So for each cell under Month Status I want the number to be divided by the Total which in this case is 30.  The number will dynamically change over time so i cannot simply divide by 30.

Sorry for the sloppy looking tables.  I am not sure how to make them look neat and lined up.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT t1.lifename, t1.monthstatus, (t1.monthstatus / t2.total * 100) as prcent FROM
 (
 select 
   decode(grouping(life), 1, 'Total', life) as "LifeName", 
 sum(case 
    when task is not null and to_char(datee, 'MM') = '08' 
      and to_char(datee, 'YYYY') = '2013' 
    then 1 
    else 0 
  end) as "MonthStatus"
from life_lk, task_c
where life_lk.life_id = task_c.life_id
group by rollup(life) ) t1
 ,
(select sum(monthstatus) as total FROM life_lk) t2 ;
```

This should work, I may have got your tables and columns wrong though

Answer (score 3):

The analytic function ratio_to_report() would probably work for you. It gives the ratio of a value to the sum of all of those values for a specified window.

In your case:

```
100* ratio_to_report(sum(...)) over ()
```

I'm not sure how it would work in the presence of a rollup, though.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions142.htm

Comment: Your concern is well founded; the subtotals will mess up the percentages. In this example, the "Total" row will get a value of 50% and 8.33%, 33.33%, 1.67%, and 6.67% for the others.

Comment: If there's just one total row then for this case I'd multiply by 2, in the absence of better thought out but more sophisticated resolutions -- eg. inline views, windowing by grouping(life)

Answer (score 1):

There are two easy ways to get the right result as the ROLLUP simply adds a grand total resulting in summing every row twice:

add PARTITION BY GROUPING(life) to the ratio_to_report

or simply multiply the result times 200 instead of 100: 200*ratio_to_report(...)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could divide by

```
SELECT COUNT (MonthStatus)
```

to get your porcentage.

Comment: if i try to divide MonthStatus by count(*) each row just ends up outputting 1

Comment: I guess it returns a value that is between 0 and 1. Try multipling the result by 100.

Comment: well the thing is i wan to divide each row under monthstatus by 30. So the dog row under percent would be 5/30 basically.  the only problem is that the number 30 will dynamically change.

Comment: Won't you always get the new value by doing COUNT(MonthStatus)?    Then the percentage would be (animal/COUNT(MonthStatus))*100